# jqPlot Pie chart Rendering but throws and error and behaaves weird?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I made a pie chart using the jqPlot and the pie chart did render, my code is mentioned below

```
var plot4 = $.jqplot('pie', [[["none",10],["error",20],["click",30],["impression",40]]], {
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions:{ sliceMargin: 0 }
        },
        legend:{ show: true }     
    });
```

the problem that I am facing is that when I hover over the Pie Chart I get an error stating

```
B.axes[D[0]]._ticks[0] is undefined
```

On the firebug console. When I click on any of the slice of the pie chart I see a much more strange occurrence where the entire slice where I clicked disappears.

Before the click the pie chart looks as follows:-

[image: Original Pie Chart]

after I click on the brown region that pie turns out to be something as shown below and even the brown slice disappears.

[image: Pie Chart without the brown slice]

Please Provide solution for the above. I have tried out different configurations but din work. And also let me tell you I am using other plugins like the bargraph and cursor on this page.

I have mentioned below the entire source code of my page where I am doing this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>jqPlot Demo</title>
<!--[if IE]><script src="./js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqplot.dragable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqplot.trendline.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.jqplot.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqPlot.css"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var lineGraph=$.jqplot('chart',  [[[10, 2],[30,5.12],[50,13.1],[70,33.6],[90,85.9],[11,20.9]]],
            {
            title:'Exponential Line',
            axes:{yaxis:{min:0,max:100},xaxis:{min:0,max:100}},
            legend:{
                show:true,
                location:'se',
                xoffset:12,
                yoffset:0
                },
            grid:{
                    gridLineColor:'#F2F2F2',
                    background:'#FFFFFF',
                    borderWidth:1,
                    borderColor:'#BBBBBB',
                    shadow:true,
                    shadowAmgle:45,
                    shadowWidth:2,
                    shadowOffset:2,
                    shadowDepth:2
                    },
           cursor:{
                     style: 'pointer',
                     show:false,
                     showTooltip: true,
                     followMouse:true,
                     tooltipOffset:10,
                     tooltipLocation:'se'
                  },
           highlighter: {
                        lineWidthAdjust: 2.5,
                        sizeAdjust: 5,          
                        showTooltip: true,     
                        tooltipLocation: 'nw', 
                        fadeTooltip: true,     
                        tooltipFadeSpeed: "fast",
                        tooltipOffset: 2,       
                        tooltipAxes: 'both',   
                        tooltipSeparator: ', ',
                        useAxesFormatters: true,
                        tooltipFormatString: '%.5P'
                    },
           seriesDefaults:{
                       trendline:{
                                show:true,
                                color:'#A2D379',
                                lable:'trendX',
                                lineWidth:2,
                                shadow:true
                                    },
                       color:'#058DC7',
                       lineWidth:5,
                       fill:true,
                       fillAndStroke:true,
                       fillColor:'#E6F4F9'
                       }

            });
    var plot4 = $.jqplot('pie', [[["none",10],["error",20],["click",30],["impression",40]]], {
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions:{ sliceMargin: 0 }
        },
        legend:{ show: true },
        cursor: {   
            show: false   
        }
    });
});
$('document').ready(function(){
        $('.column').sortable({
            connectWith:'.column',
            handle:'h2',
            cursor:'move',
            placeholder:'placeholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize:true,
            opacity:0.4,
            revert:true

        }).disableSelection();
}


    );
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="column" id="column1">
        <div class="dragbox" id="item1" >
            <h2>Handle 1</h2>
            <div class="dragbox-content" >
                <div id="chart" style="width:100%;height:100%;float:left"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="column" id="column1">
        <div class="dragbox" id="item1" >
            <h2>Handle 1</h2>
            <div class="dragbox-content" >
                <div id="pie" style="width:100%;height:100%;float:left"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="column" id="column1">
        <div class="dragbox" id="item1" >
            <h2>Handle 1</h2>
            <div class="dragbox-content" >
                <div id="chart1" style="width:400px;height:300px;float:left"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>


<div id="barRender" style="width:400px;height:300px;float:left"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even the error I get has a JavaScript link below as usual(If there is some thing wrong with the javaScript file or we dont to things as expected firebug points to the file). It links to jqplot.cursor.min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got the answer to the Question. We just need to remove one line of the code and things work great after that

```
 $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
```

As I remove the above I am invoking individual plugins whenever required and wherever required. When this statement was there then all the plugins were enabled and that was the reason for the weird output.

Comment: Hello
I am getting two errors while using jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js 1) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null  2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PieRenderer' of null

Answer (score 0):

For the part of your problem you are missing the highlighter plugin. If you add it it will work fine for the dragging of [the points on the line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/ZkWcz/9/). It doesn't throw exceptions but for some reason dragging looks ugly. I checked and it doesn't look ugly if you disable `fill` in `seriesDefaults` apparently they have some conflict.

As I observed the pie chart doesn't link the dragable script as it behaves all right when it is disabled.

**EDIT:**

I figure out how to enable the dragable for a particular plugin which @Shiv Kumar Ganesh used to solve the problem.
[It is show here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/ZkWcz/12/) Important are: to set `isDragable: true` for `series`, and `show: true` for `highlighter`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I found that the problem was something else. Thanks anyways :)